# Bucket creation failing for hosting website

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to host a static website using GCS. For the same, I am trying to create a storage bucket inside GCS with the following name:
amp.dropshipstepbystep.com

The domain has been verified and successfully added to search console.

Keep getting the following error every time bucket with "amp.dropshipstepbystep.com" is created.

> To create a bucket with domain name amp.dropshipstepbystep.com, first
>   show that you control the domain. Visit Bucket Name Verification to
>   learn how.

Error screenshot attached.
[image]

Comment: Turns out, hosting on GCS needs a CNAME entry for storage bucket.
www.example.com       CNAME    c.storage.googleapis.com.

See GCP documentation on [Hosting a Static Website](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website)